# Change constraints based on text length

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

I have two labels, that are ordered like this:

`H:[label1]-10-[label2]`

I want to change their order, based on the first label's length. So, if its text won't fit on one line, I want to change the constraints to look like this:

`V:[label1]-2.5-[label2]`

Here are my constraints right now:

```
    [self.containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_carLabel]-2.5-[_statusLabel]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_carLabel]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_statusLabel]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

And this is how I want them to look, when `_carLabel` won't fit in one line:

```
    [self.containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_carLabel]-10-[_statusLabel]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_carLabel]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_statusLabel]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

How would I do this?

Comment: NSAttributedString would be easy options instead of playing with constraints at runtime.

Comment: The problem is, that I receive the contents of both labels dynamically from a server. So, they might change, while the app is being used.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to conditionally apply constraints based on the size of the label.  I don't believe there's a way to add both constraints and have this work how you described.  (Though if it is possible it will likely have to do with setting the priority of each constraint `@"[label1]-10@99-[label2]"` and `@"V:[label1]-2.5@98-[label2]` but I was unable to get that to work.  The code below however seems to do what you're looking for.

```
UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:label1];
    [label1 setText:@"Small text"];
//    [label1 setText:@"Some really long text to test the other scenario also works"];

    UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:label2];
    [label2 setText:@"Small text 2"];

    [label1 sizeToFit];
    if (label1.frame.size.width + kPadding + label2.frame.size.width < self.view.frame.size.width) {
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[label1]-padding@100-[label2]"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                          metrics:@{@"padding": @(kPadding)}
                                                                            views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label1, label2)]];
    } else {
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[label1]-2.5@100-[label2]"
                                                options:0
                                                metrics:nil
                                                   views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label1, label2)]];
    }
```

Comment: The problem is, that this all happens in a custom view, that is dynamically initialized, based on a response from a server. Since I am using AutoLayout, at the time of initialization (when I invoke your code), the frame is 0 and it always sets the second constraints.

Comment: So you can't set the text at the time the constraint is built?

Comment: I can, but it might change at runtime, so I have to dynamically change the constraints.

Comment: You could potentially keep the logic above and observe changes to the label.  As the label changes (possibly adding target with value changed as the trigger ::untested::) you could remove constraints and add new ones (keeping the current constraints that apply to this specifically in a property).